# isBase64Encoded always false in API Gateway request to AWS Proxy Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have this API Gateway which on a POST hits a lambda integrated using AWS-PROXY.

My request class looks like this:

```
public class ApiGatewayProxyRequest {
    private String resource;
    private String path;
    private String httpMethod;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private Map<String, String> queryStringParameters;
    private Map<String, String> pathParameters;
    private Map<String, String> stageVariables;
    private Context context;
    private String body;
    private boolean isBase64Encoded;
    ... snip
}
```

I am hitting the API gateway sending files on the POST request, the files contents are later available in the body field of my APIGatewayProxyRequest, this is all good.

Problem is that I want binary data to be Base64 encoded and all non-binary data to be left as is.

So I added multiple binary types to BinaryMediaTypes of my API Gateway. These files (when the Content-Type header is correctly set) cause the files to be correctly encoded as base64 in the body of the request.

Now the problem I'm having: despite the API Gateway correctly encoding the files as base64, the field isBase64Encoded field on the request is **never** true, it's always being received as false.

Any idea why? according to the documentation, this field should contain a boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request paylad is Base64 encoded.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Thank you